# Not able to insert data into oracle Table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created one table called as Booking.

Structure of Booking is

[image]

I am inserting the data using below syntax :-

```
INSERT INTO Booking (
(id,price,date1,c_id)
values(1,1235.01,'2016-10-11', 1));
```

but I am getting **ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword** error.
I am using Oracle apex application.

what is the problem with this query?

Comment: two extra brackets. INSERT INTO Booking (id,price,date1,c_id) values(1,1235.01,'2016-10-11', 1);

Comment: the precision problem is due to price (4,2) you need at least (6,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the extra set of parens.  Second, one of the values is presumably a date (as opposed to a string).  I would suggest:

```
INSERT INTO Booking (id, price, date1, c_id)
    VALUES (1, 1235.01, DATE '2016-10-11', 1);
```

The `DATE` keyword interprets the following string as a date.

This will still fail, because `price` has six digits, instead of four.  Either lower the price or increase the size of the `price` column.

Comment: thanks that got fixed but still something is wrong again Getting "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"  error. All seems to be fine. Don't know for which column it is talking about

Comment: @SaurabhGarg . . . `price` is declared as `(4, 2)`.  It needs to be at least `(6, 2)` to fit this value.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO Booking (id,price,date1,c_id)
values(1,1235.01,to_date('2016-10-11','yyyy-mm-dd'), 1)
;
```

1. there was an extra set of parentheses that had to be removed
2. the string holding a date needs to be converted into a date, this can be done using the very flexible to_date() function, or if the string is strictly in YYYY-MM-DD format you can use DATE.
3. when creating a decimal field the first number is the TOTAL number of digits, an the second number is the number of digits after the decimal point. So 4,2 allow -99.99 to 99.99 as the maximum. To store 1235.01 you need at least 6 digits so 6,2 as a minimum.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: @DerekBrown: that seems to be the normal logic only. he is just converting the string to date

Comment: @SaurabhGarg I understand- but it was marked as Low Quality because it was code-only.  The new version looks a lot better!

Comment: "2017-11-17 01:46:49Z" -v- "2017-11-17 01:46:01Z"(mine)  whilst mine was first I got distracted, by the time I came back to it Gordon had added more. You will also see my comment under the question. I didn't seem necessary to elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Booking(id,price,date1,c_id) values(1,1235.01,'2016-10-11', 1);

INSERT INTO Booking (id,price,date1,c_id)values(1,1235.01,to_date('2016-10-11','yyyy-mm-dd'), 1)
;
```

**Both of these are correct answers.**

I would definitely recommend you use references as they would help you in further understanding and writing better and complex queries in the future.

I usually follow W3Schools for that purpose.

I am attaching [a link here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) so that you can access that particular web page for more info.